# Insert empty DateTime from C# into FoxPro

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-foxpro

I am trying to insert an empty `DateTime` into a FoxPro database using `DbParameter` in C#. Our application marries FoxPro data along with SQL Server and .NET models/data.

My current issue is that most of our `DateTime` types in C# are not nullable, nor should they be. However, most of our legacy data in FoxPro are empty dates (shown as ' / / : : '). I am trying to do an insert into the FoxPro table where I do a check to see if the .NET `DateTime` meets certain criteria, then inserts an empty date. This last part has proven to be a nightmare.

What I have tried so far:

```
.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, new DateTime())
```

The above understandably inserts `01/01/0001` but is not what we want.

```
.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, "{}")
.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, "{:://}")
.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, "{//}")
.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, "'{}'")
```

The above all result in

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch'.

which makes sense because I'm trying to send a `string` to a field with `DateTime` type.

Does anyone know how to insert an empty `DateTime` into FoxPro?

Comment: Could you share your insert statement as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're not using a `DbParameter`, but rather an `OleDbParameter`, and you're adding them through the [`OleDbParameterCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add) method?

If so, consider that you are using the overload that is `.Add(String, Object)`, and you could instead use the overload that is `.Add(String, OleDbType)`:

```cs
.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, OleDbType.Date)
```

The default value of an `OleDbParameter` is `null`, so you don't need to do anything more for your empty dates.

Also, depending on how the column is defined in your FoxPro database schema, it may be appropriate to pass `OleDbType.Date`, `OleDbType.DBDate`, `OleDbType.DBTime`, or `OleDbType.DBTimeStamp`.  The [full list of OleDB types is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbtype), but I'm not entirely certain how they align to FoxPro's data types.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Alas, we are using a `DbParameter` as we toggle between `FoxPro` and `MSSQL` endlessly. Rather than have two separate libraries we've been using one. So using `OleDbParamater` throws a `Data type mismatch`.

Comment: So if I use `OleDb` for everything (connection, parameters, etc.) it seems to work. So looks like I'm doing a massive code find and replace...yay...

Comment: Well, that's a bit confusing because `DbParameterCollection` doesn't have an `Add` method that takes more than one argument, so I'm not sure if you are using some extension method or something?

Comment: Sorry, should have said I'm using the single argument add.

Comment: No problem.  Hope you are able to get it all working. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your second example is close, but you have the Date and Time portions reversed.

It should be `.Parameters.Add(string.Empty, "{//::}")`

The `//` represent the Date portion, and the `::` the Time portion.

Comment: No luck :( also throws `Data type mismatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your SQL-Insert statement for VFP, but you MAY need to adjust it and do TWO different inserts.  One IF a date exists, another if it does not.

For the one that does NOT have a date, I would hard-enter the following (for example where the "?" are the parameter place-holders)

```
insert into yourTable ( fld1, fld2,..., YourDateField ) values ( ?, ?, ..., ctot('') )
```

the function CTOT() means character to datetime and an empty string will comply with expected VFP Date/time field.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me.

```cs
Parameters.AddWithValue("CreateDate", new DateTime(1899,12,30,0,0,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately to insert an empty date you must not include the field of type date in the SQL INSERT statement. You'll need an INSERT statement to include the field when it has data, and another for when it needs to be empty.

Additionally you must execute the SET NULL OFF statement so that the missing field is inserted blank instead of null. I think this field can be set from the connection string, but I prefer to modify the behavior via a boolean parameter in my ExecNoQuery method.

```
int n1 = ExecNoQuery("INSERT INTO myTable(name, dateVisit) VALUES('Tom', {^2023/05/29})");
int n2 = ExecNoQuery("INSERT INTO myTable(name) VALUES('The one that never comes')", false);

public int ExecNoQuery(string sSQL, bool setNullOn = true)
{
    int res = 0;
    using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        cnn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        if (setNullOn == false)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("SET NULL OFF", cnn);
            res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sSQL, cnn);
        res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return res;
}
```

If you need to use the OleDbParameter, omit that OleDbParameter.